# PHP Get Facebook username?

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to get a php page to display "Leave a comment, '%fullname' " without having to use that method that the user has to grant permission for the app, can I do it in another easier way  (maybe even without using the app method) that doesn't interrupt with the user's experience when browsing through pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There´s a very simple answer to that: No.

Without authorization, you cannot get any personal data of the user. But there are several Social Plugins, you might want to try them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

If you know the User ID, you can use this way (or the Graph API):

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/fb:name/

But to get the ID, you still need to authorize the user.